Measuring the position of entry and exit holes when drilling blind
I need a hole (for a cable) from a cupboard, through a ceiling and into my loft. I know exactly where I need the hole to be in the cupboard ceiling, but I can't get a drill into that space. So, the hole needs to be made from the loft space.
However, between where the hole needs to emerge in the cupboard, and where it needs to start, are two walls and a hatch. Hence, I can't easily work out where to start drilling.
I figure I need a way to "survey the land" so that I can determine where to start drilling - basically a series of right angled lines that lead from the cupboard to the hatch, up through the hatch and back to where the hole needs to start.
But, I've no idea on how to do such a task with any accuracy.

Some diagrams or photos would help

What sort of cable? Mains electricity, computer network, a doorbell...?

You can't get a drill into that space, so consider using a right-angle drill or a right-angle drill adapter.

use a long screw as a marker ... drive it into the ceiling by hand ... look for it in the loft

Sometimes a long wire through the ceiling close to the blind drill spot can give a close reference to measure from above.
Then put a little spackle to cover the tiny hole afterward.
Start with a short drill bit of same diameter as the wire to get the hole in place. Mind that there may be stuff above the ceiling, like wires or pipes, so don't drill hard and fast. Go slow, and stop if you feel resistance. Then insert the wire into the hole. Then go upstairs and find it.
This should get you close to the correct spot without all the angles and zig zags.

It can be safer to start with a shorter drill bit to give the long drill bit some guidance and not suddenly bend to a right angle.

Very true, @AndrewMorton ! Will add that in.

It's often possible to identify the tops of walls from above, also light switch  cables may be a useful landmark.
If the cupboard ceiling is made of plasterboard you don't need a drill to make a hole. if you can reach the location with your hand any pointed tool can ba used like an awl or a screwdriver.
